# Does Carrier frequency offset (CFO) means difference of the message frequency and integrator?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-modulation, bit-error

Can anyone here tell me what is CFO? Initially, I thought it might be when the message signal **mi**, that is 
$$r(t) = 2P cos(2\pi fc*fi+\delta f)$$ doesn't match with integrator  $$\int_0^T r(t) *  cos((2 \pi(fc + fk)t )dt$$ when **fi** doesn't match **fk** then we have a value of $$\delta f $$and that is CFO but I think it isn't the case as some times fi matches fk but still we have an equation for CFO? And can someone tell me how it affects BER? Should we multiply  $$y= h*x + N $$ with CFO factor?

Source : 
[enter link description here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel4/26/8633/00380125.pdf?casa_token=HDBZ0IEWCTQAAAAA:ewYZi-Ni0LW0pNhQ3TI-H_bd_JV6dRrhLUCWSysQnaHpMgMNIlKAEWb_i1RWGx18awbvQ4Xuc6g)

Comment: What is the bigger context here?

Comment: @Andyaka The bigger context here is that how the can CFO exist if the message signal and the integrator have the same frequency?  Does CFO itself is a separate phenomenon? What is it that is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: and one more thing how it affected BER? How can I try to simulate it in MATLAB? Should I multiply receive signal with equation-9 in link paper

Comment: Well I don't understand the context but, if I take as being one of receiving data correctly then the integrator is used to "drive-out" any frequency error.

Comment: @good_omen92 you need even bigger context. CFO is something that only exist when considering a whole system: transmitter, receiver and channel. It's not something that's "element" of a signal, but can manifest as such, but only if the receiver or the transmitter doesn't compensate that, which again, depends on the system you're looking at. However, an integrator doesn't have a frequency - I think you might be misusing the word "integrator"? Maybe for "downconverter"? I don't know – you need to be more precise in your wording.